# How to see on Linux what network interface and source IP address is used for a route to a specific destination host?

Tags: linux, networking, linux-networking

If I have multiple network interfaces (here: 2) on a Linux machine (here: Debian Lenny).
How do I see, over what network interface (NIC) a route to a specific destination host is going and what source IP address is used by default?

I have though of using

```
ping -I nic1 desthost.example.com
ping -I nic2 desthost.example.com
```

too see if both ways are possible. (Here: Both ways are possible)

I looked up the routing table

```
ip route show
```

But it's quite complex, so I thought, there must by a small simple tool, to just tell me:

"To destination host desthost.example.com it takes interface nicX and source IP address 10.0.0.1"

What is the simplest way of getting this information?

(And I'd rather not use tcpdump and set the interfaces in promiscous mode.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Use `ip route get <ip>`.

Comment: And to get only the interface: `ip -o route get $ipaddress | perl -nle 'if(/dev\s+(\S+)/) {print $1}'`

Comment: or `ip -o route get $ipaddress | awk '{ print $5 }'`

Comment: ip -6 route get 240b:c020:104:5422:bb27:2:1d:134 for example doest print anything. But its pingable

Answer (score 0):

what about `route -C`

Comment: route is deprecated. use iproute2.

Comment: Please make the answer somewhat more complete (e.g. *explain*). If I try the command I just get a header.

Answer (score 0):

I use `netstat -Wcatnp` . You should try this command.

Comment: Recent Linuxes dropped `netstat` in favor of `ss`.

Answer (score 0):

Even easier, I'd say `nm-tool` and if you only want the relevant line `nm-tool | grep Device`. That should output:

```
- Device: wlan0  [My router name] -----------------------------------------------
```

Comment: What is `nm-tool` and in what package is it provided? Something related to NetworkManager?

Comment: Yes, it required NetworkManager (which is not installed universally).